# How to change charset of table/column - Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table:
[image]

Can i change charset of column `SCHEMA_ERD` to `UTF-8`?
If it isn't possible maybe i can change charset only for that table?

**Can someone give me example how to do it?**
I want to keep emojis inside that `SCHEMA_ERD` that is why i need change charset to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, in Oracle, character set is database's characteristic. It means that you should change character set for the whole database (i.e. you can't do that for only one table (or column, or schema).

**However**, you could use `NVARCHAR2` or `NCLOB` so I suggest you to try it. Because, changing character set is not that simple task.

Comment: Well then.. NCLOB will be like CLOB but the only difference is fact i will be able to hold my emoji inside of it?

Comment: As I said, I suggest you try it. It is way simpler than changing database's character set. Alternatively, if it doesn't help, see whether storing emojis as **images** (in BLOB) helps.

Comment: okay i changed that type to NCLOB and everything works fine now, thanks! :P

Answer (score 2):

Issue this query to see your available character sets in your database

```
select * from  nls_database_parameters
where parameter in ( 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');

PARAMETER                 VALUE     
------------------------- ----------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    AL16UTF16 
NLS_CHARACTERSET          WE8ISO8859P1
```

The character set in `NLS_CHARACTERSET` is what is used for *normal* `VARCHAR2`.

The `NCHAR` character set is used for `NVARCHAR2` or `NCLOB`.

You have no other chance wihtout support of your **DBA**

But note, that the `NCHAR` character set is typically set to support `UTF8` or `UTF16` so it should work for you.